# $y''(x)+2 x y'(x)+\left(x^2+1\right) y(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I constructed this equation so that it would have a double root for $e^{-x^2/2}$.

I basically applied $(D+x)(D+x)y$, which gave me this equation.

The solution is $c_1 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}+c_2 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} x$

However, I'm unable reverse this process (without using my prior knowledge of the solution, of course)

How would this equation be solved?

Comment: Please do not use question titles consisting exclusively of a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is a bit ad hoc, but it occurred fairly straightforwardly.

Start by setting $z(x)=y'(x)+xy$ and the equation becomes $z'(x)+xz(x)=0$

Then you solve $z'+xz=0$ for $z$, and then the related equation $y'+xy=z$ for $y$.

For the first of these you can separate the variables to obtain $$\ln z +C=-\frac {x^2}2$$ or $$z=Ae^{-\frac {x^2}2}$$ giving then $$y'+xy=Ae^{-\frac {x^2}2}$$

Then, to eliminate the exponential set $y=f(x)e^{-\frac {x^2}2}$ to obtain $$f'e^{-\frac {x^2}2}-xfe^{-\frac {x^2}2}+xfe^{-\frac {x^2}2}=Ae^{-\frac {x^2}2}$$

Cancel the non-zero exponential and note the terms which cancel, to obtain $f'=A$ so that $f=Ax+B$.

Comment: Could you come up with z=y'+xy if I only wrote the equation? I am doubtful. Factoring the equation is the whole point.

Comment: @grdgfgr That's how I did it. I was looking for a substitution which would reduce it to a first order equation. I'm obviously going to have $xy$ in there, because that will give me an $xy'$ term but I don't want anything to multiply $y''$ so I need something like $z=ay'+(bx+c)y+?$ where $?$ is something I might adjust later. And then I equate coefficients. So it is a very hands on method. Once I have the linear equation, it turns out to be easy to go from there.

Comment: Okay. I tried to match (D+ax+b)(D+cx+d)y which gave the same result.